# Community user rejecting edit and a another user performing the edit

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, community-user, rejected-edits, rejection-reasons

I know this question has appeared several times, but as I do not find a proper explanation I want to show my case:

- I suggested an edit on tag [alias](/questions/tagged/alias) excerpt because there was a typo.
- The edit was approved by two users
- Community user rejected it
- Another user edited what I had suggested
- I got a "rejected" message

This is the case: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1660245

Comment: minitech is not a moderator (yet).

Comment: minitech did far more than fix that simple typo.

Comment: @J.Steen . My suggested edit was for the whole tag: excerpt and text, but it somehow was split in two different suggestions.

Comment: FYI, this is the full edit Minitech made: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10872686/revisions

Comment: And also a dupe of [How do suggested edits work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251)

Comment: @fedorqui You stated in your question "suggested edit on tag alias excerpt", so I focused on that. =)

Comment: The reviewer thought there was more to fix so considered your edit as too minor; can't judge him for that.

Comment: It happened again! http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1707149

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When presented with a suggested edit a reviewer has four options

- They can accept it, giving it one vote to accept,
- reject it, giving it a vote to reject,
- they can improve it, which allows them to edit the post based on your revision,
- or they can skip the edit entirely.

When improving a post the reviewer has the option of specifying if the suggested edit was helpful, if they say it was, it is approved, if they say it wasn't it is rejected.  The Community user does the actual approving/rejecting because his vote is binding.

Comment: Thanks, @Servy. Now it makes sense to me. What I do not understand is why he marked it as `rejected`. Of course it was just a tiny thing what I suggested, but it was in the good direction.

Comment: @fedorqui clearly he felt it was too minor of an edit.

Comment: @fedorqui: because your edit was too minor; when suggesting edits, you need to fix more than just a typo, please.

Comment: OK. I would state that it is not bad to correct typos, but can also be seen as a good way to make you improve the article whenever you want to correct tiny things. Thanks people (although all down votes I received).